# gulp-sourcemaps points sources to wrong directory

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-sourcemaps

I'm trying to create source maps for my sass and js files with gulp-sourcemaps, but the path in `sources: [ ... ]` is always only relative to the source and not to the destination directory.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project
|-- public/
|   |-- css/
|   |   |-- main.scss
|   |   `-- dashboard.scss
|   |-- js/
|   |   |-- dashboard/
|   |   |   `-- dashboard.js
|   |   `-- app.js
|   |-- index.html
|   |-- app.min.js
|   |-- app.min.js.map
|   |-- style.css
|   `-- style.css.map
`-- gulpfile.js
```

And these are my two gulp tasks:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    // only need main.scss because I'm using @import
    return gulp
        .src('./public/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(rename('style.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});

gulp.task('uglify', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(['./public/js/app.js', './public/js/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(concat('app.concat.js'))
            .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public'));
});
```

After running those tasks the map files look like this:

```
{"version":3,"sources":"main.scss","dashboard.scss"], ... }
{"version":3,"sources":["app.js","dashboard/dashboard.js"], ... }
```

But I would expect them to be relative their actual directory

```
{"version":3,"sources":["css/main.scss","css/dashboard.scss"], ... }
{"version":3,"sources":["js/app.js","js/dashboard/dashboard.js"], ... }
```

So how can I get the desired result? What's wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

To control the path of sources in a sourcemap file using gulp-sourcemaps, you should pass an options parameter to the sourcemaps.write command, in which you specify a relative directory for sourceRoot.  For example:

```js
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  var stream = gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
      .pipe(plugin1())
      .pipe(plugin2())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false, sourceRoot: '/src'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

This snippet is taken from the [gulp-sourcemaps documentation](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#write-options).  For an example, see this GitHub [repository](https://github.com/tonysneed/Experimental.TsGulpDebug), where I use gulp-sourcemaps with gulp-typescript to map generated javascript source files back to typescript files.

Comment: Hi, documentation says that sourceRoot should be relative to the path where source-maps are generated but actually when i tested, then it is relative to the gulpfile.js.

*In this case for a file written to dist/subdir/example.js, the source map is written to dist/subdir/example.js.map and the sourceRoot will be ../../src (resulting in the full source path ../../src/subdir/example.js).*

But sourceRoot which actually worked for me was /src as per your answer in ubuntu. Need to update doc.

Comment: Although sourceRoot is in doc, i was not using that at all in earlier for windows system. Don;t know whether node version issue or system :)